# Rendered form does not have controller variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

**controller action**

```
def board
   @ids = params[:ids] if params[:ids]
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        render :edit_modal
      end
   end
end
```

**edit_modal.js.erb**

```
$("#editModal .js-modal-body").html(
  "<%= j render "edit_board.html.erb" %>"
);

$('#editModal').modal('show');
```

**edit_board.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for :order_fulfillment,
 url: update_multiple_path,
 method: :patch,
 remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :edit_ids, value: @ids %>
<% end %>
```

For some weird reason, my form does not have any value inside the hidden fields. However, when I do a `binding.pry` like this:

```
def board
   @ids = params[:ids] if params[:ids]
   binding.pry
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        render :edit_modal
      end
   end
end
```

The form seems to have the value of @ids populated. `binding.pry` halts the program at that line of execution. I am unable to understand why this works with `binding.pry`? Is it because @ids does not have any values when `edit_modal.js.erb` is rendered ? if that is the case why, is it so, and how can I make `@ids` to be populated inside my `edit_board.html.erb`.

Answer (score 1):

Rename .js file to action name you don't need to render them explicitly

```
def board
   @ids = params[:ids] if params[:ids]
   binding.pry
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
end
```

rename `edit_modal.js.erb` => board.js.erb

it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to change several codes here

**Controller**

To use ajax in rails, you only add `format.js`

```
def board
   @ids = params[:ids] if params[:ids]
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
end
```

Then, rename `edit_modal.js.erb` into `board.js.erb` because you have to use file same as your method. Inside of your `board.js.erb` you have to change into

```
$("#editModal .js-modal-body").html(
  "<%= j render "edit_board" %>"
);

$('#editModal').modal('show');
$('#order_edit_ids').value("<%= @ids %>");
```

Finally. Rename `edit_board.html.erb` to use underscore `_edit_board.html.erb`

I hope this help you.